# onclick handler in custom exporting button in highcharts-vue fails with 'Cannot read property 'call' of undefined'

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I want to put a custom export button with its own `onclick` into a HighStock chart via `highcharts-vue` using the configuration option described in https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons .
I can make the button appear, but sadly, any click on it causes an error:

> TypeError
> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

The code to reproduce this error can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-exporting-error-znvwy .
I'm using Vue 2.6.11, highcharts-vue 1.3.5 and HighCharts 8.1.0 (8.2.2 shows the same error).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `onclick` function is defined outside of your `customButton` object, and so Highcharts are not able to find event function to call your handler. Just need to move the function into the `customButton`, and then it should work well.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/981nbkur/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.onclick

Kind regards!